How will the Words "Those who pierce him will see him" be fulfilled
Concerning the Second coming of Jesus , someone made a Comment
How can “those who pierced him” see him unless they’re resurrected? Jesus is supposed to return before the millennial reign but the resurrection of the wicked won’t take place until the thousand years are over.
The scripture In concern is
Rev 1:
7 Look, he is coming with the clouds,” and “every eye will see him, even those who pierced him"; and all peoples on earth “will mourn because of him.” So shall it be! Amen.

Answer
The words “Those who pierced Him will see Him” will be fulfilled when the Jews in Jerusalem and all over the world will see Christ coming on the clouds at the Second Coming.
Explanation
The fact is, Revelation 1:7 is not a stand-alone verse; it is a direct quote from Daniel 7:13 and Zechariah 12:10 clubbed together.
Zechariah 12:10 says:

“And I will pour on the house of David, and on those living in
Jerusalem, the Spirit of grace and of prayers. And they shall
look on Me whom they have pierced; and they shall mourn for Him, as
one mourns for an only son, and they shall be bitter over Him, like
the bitterness over the first-born”.

It is very clear that the antecedent of “they” in “they shall look on Me” is those living in Jerusalem including “the house of David”.
Who are the people living in Jerusalem?
Of course, God gave the land of Canaan to Abraham and his children forever. But in the aftermath of a civil war in Israel after the death of King Solomon, the kingdom was divided into northern kingdom (Kingdom of Israel) with capital at Samaria and southern kingdom (Kingdom of Judea) with capital at Jerusalem.
But it was Jerusalem that God chose for His name to reside.

“Jehovah had said, In Jerusalem I will put My name” (2 King 21:4).

But it was the Kingdom of Judah that God chose for Himself.

“but He elected the tribe of Judah (Jews), the Mount Zion which He
loved” (Psalms 78:68).

So, after the Chaldean King Sargon attacked and subdued the northern Israel, they never came back as organized as the people of God.
No wonder, the Jews kept on coming back to Jerusalem, making Isaiah’s prophecy true:

“Except Jehovah of Hosts had left a remnant for us, a few, we would be
as Sodom; we would be as Gomorrah (that is, completely wiped out)”
(Isaiah 1:9).

So, we see that “those living in Jerusalem” in God’s eyes are the Jews!
Since King David is from the tribe of Judah, he and his family are Jews too.
Thus, we see that the people who will see the Messiah at the Second Coming and mourn for Him are the Jews who rejected Him all these 2000 years. They still reject Him. It is the Jews living in Jerusalem during the First Coming of Jesus that betrayed Him and caused Him to be crucified (pierced).
Then the conclusion we get is that the Jews who will be living in Jerusalem at the time of the Second Coming will see Jesus on the clouds and will mourn for Him.
Jews or Romans
There is an erroneous theory that there is going to be a “special resurrection” of the wicked people who really pierced Jesus at the crucifixion.
The real people who pierced Jesus are a couple of Roman soldiers who simply carried out their duty. Even if these people are resurrected specially, they may feel sorry and may repent. But I don’t think they will “mourn for Jesus as one mourns for an only son and bitter for a firstborn son”.
This theory arises when Revelation is considered as a stand-alone verse. But when we understand the background verse of Zechariah 12:10 which is quoted in Revelation 1:7, we will see that “those Jews” living in Jerusalem at the time of the Second Coming will mourn and bitter for Jesus as one mourn for an only son and bitter for a firstborn son.
Why will they do so?
Because first of all, Jesus Himself was a Jew (Heb 7:14) and secondly they will realize that Jesus indeed was the Messiah they were eagerly waiting for all these millennia yet had rejected earlier.
No Wicked Resurrection for 1000 Years
Scripture is very clear:
“This is the first resurrection. Blessed and holy is the one having part in the first resurrection. The second death has no authority over these, but they will be priests of God and of Christ, and will reign with Him a thousand years” (Rev 20:5-6).
Only the saints (“blessed and holy ones”) will be resurrected in the first resurrection at the Second Coming.
“But the rest of the dead did not live again until the thousand years were ended” (verse 5).
There is no exception here.
The “rest of the dead” are definitely not holy and are no saints, for had they been, they would have taken part in the first resurrection!
So, the wicked people who pierced Jesus, whether Jews or Romans, will not have any special resurrection.
Conclusion
So, “those Jews who will be living in Jerusalem” at the time of the Second Advent are the people who will see Jesus and mourn for Him. This will be the fulfillment of Zechariah 12:10 prophecy which was quoted in Revelation 1:7.

This is a Beautiful answer. So you are saying that "Jews" there is National not Individual. ?

@FaithMendel – Thank you for your comment. I meant the “generation” of Jews living in Jerusalem at that time. Jesus also said the same thing when He said: “Truly I say to you, Not at all will this generation (the Jewish people) pass away until all these things occur” (Mark 13:30).

If it is the same Generation. Then it means that generation would be Resurrected

@FaithMendel – when I said “generation”, I meant this meaning: “Thayer G1074: 2) that which has been begotten, men of the same stock, a family” (that means Jews). As I said in my answer, “those living (not resurrected) in Jerusalem” (the stock of Jews) at the Second Coming shall see Him whom they (the stock of Jews) have caused to be pierced.

Revelation 1:7 corelated with two prophetic messages in Daniel 7:13 and Zechariah 12:10;
Daniel 7:13 NIV

“In my vision at night I looked, and there before me was one like a son of man, coming with the clouds of heaven. He approached the Ancient of Days and was led into his presence.

Zechariah 12:10 NIV

“And I will pour out on the house of David and the inhabitants of Jerusalem a spirit of grace and supplication. They will look on me, the one they have pierced, and they will mourn for him as one mourns for an only child, and grieve bitterly for him as one grieves for a firstborn son.

Revelation 1:7 describes three significant events


“Look, he is coming with the clouds,” (ref. Daniel 7:13)
and “every eye will see him, even those who pierced him”; (ref. Zechariah 12:10)
and all peoples on earth “will mourn because of him.” (ref. Zechariah 12:10; Matthew 24:30). So shall it be! Amen.


The prophecies in Daniel 7:13 and Zechariah 12:10 refer to distinct events. Zechariah 12:10 speaks of the future restoration of the Israelites. According to Benson Commentary;

Zechariah tells us, they should themselves be first changed, and repent heartily of that sin which had been the cause of their fall, for God should pour out on them the spirit of grace and supplication, that they might look with compunction of heart on him whom they had pierced; and he should, by his Spirit, improve those good dispositions into a thorough conviction of his being the Messiah, whom they had rejected: for this they should weep bitterly, Zechariah 12:11, and make earnest supplications till received again into his grace and favor.

The third event mentions "all people", including the Gentiles. In Matthew 24:30, Jesus says;

Then will appear the sign of the Son of Man in heaven. And then all the peoples of the earth will mourn when they see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory. (NIV)

For those on earth who are against Him, His return signifies final judgement. These people will mourn because it will be too late to repent for what is about to happen.
